# Google Cloud Endpoints + IOS + Google SignIn Library : Failed to build my app

Tags: ios, google-cloud-endpoints, google-signin

I'm trying to using Google Endpoints in an iOS Client with Swift 2.0.
So I've followed this doc: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios.

I've already generate and import on my IOS project all the required files as I'm suppose to do. But **when I tried to build** my IOS App, I've got that error:

> ld: library not found for -lGIDExShared

I figured out that **when I'm upgrading** [GoogleSignIn Library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/) on 2.4.0, error changed and I'm getting:

> ld: library not found for -lGIPNSURL+FIFE

Finally, when ***I'm removing GoogleSignIn Library***, everything works fine and **my app is building correctly**..

What's wrong ? I can't remove forever GoogleSignIn because I need it on my app..